# Intellisense - Hide inherited members?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

My coworkers and I were just discussing an annoyance we have in Visual Studio. If you're working with a class that's inherited from another large class, like `Controller`, you're going to have a huge list of inherited members in intellisense. Sometimes, you only want to see your own members that you defined yourself, instead of having to find things amongst a huge list of other things.

I suppose that if you're looking for something you defined, you should know what it's called. But I know I've run into this frustration when classes get a bit more complicated. Is there a built in way to have intellisense hide the inherited things, or maybe is there a plugin somewhere that provides this? Otherwise I guess one of us has to write it.

Comment: I assume you are referring to intellisense on the C# side?  It behaves differently between different languages: XAML and especially VB.

Comment: I think you are looking for `System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute`

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/members.asp) has such a feature. It allows you to push inherited members to the end of the list and more:

> Access non-inherited entries quickly by having them listed first.
>   Scroll to see entries from base classes.
>
> Enable this feature in the options dialog. Use in combination with
>   bolding of non-inherited members and shrinking for optimal efficiency.
>
> This feature can also be enabled or disabled dynamically from the
>   filtering toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx